# Как сделать чтобы дискорд бот имел доступ только одному чату?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

У меня есть дискорд-бот, но он имеет доступ ко всем чатам на сервере ,как можно его ограничить, чтобы он имел доступ только одному чату?

Вот код бота:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   if int(message.channel.id) != 818865123204005899:
      return


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    content = message.content
    await send(content, message.channel.id)
    await message.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def send_msg(channel_id, msg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)

async def send(what, where):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_msg(where, what), bot.loop)


bot.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте ид канала куда было отправлено сообщение. Если оно не равняется нужному иду канала, то возвращайте пустоту

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if int(message.channel.id) != 818865123204005899:
        return
```

Comment: Я не могу понят почему то не работает бот аноним чата, но хоть я айди чата ставлю бот реагирует во всех чатах почему то?

Comment: @Phantom await process_commands(message) должен быть уже после этой проверки

Comment: @Phantom и должен быть только один on_message. Перенесите ваш код со второго on_message в первый